# setQuery in searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I would like to setText in my searchView in Android App. setQuery doesn't work.

this is my Code:

```
 private SearchView searchPostalDelivery;
        private PostalDeliveriesAdapter listAdapter;
        private ExpandableListView myList;

        private ArrayList<PostalDeliveries> postalDeliveryList = new ArrayList<PostalDeliveries>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_single_delivery);

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchPostalDelivery = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchPostalDelivery);
            searchPostalDelivery.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchPostalDelivery.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchPostalDelivery.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            searchPostalDelivery.setOnCloseListener(this);


             searchPostalDelivery.setQuery("test", false);



        }
```

}

Comment: You want set a hint or a search query?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution:

```
final String query = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query) && mSearchView != null){

        mSearchView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mSearchItem);
                mSearchView.setQuery(query, true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
searchPostalDelivery.setQueryHint("Query Hint");
```

if you want to invoke your searchable activity you can do :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this,MySearchableActivity.class);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,"Your barcode");
    startActivity(i);
```

and in your searchable activity you can read your query.

Comment: first delete your answer and use comment, second `I want set code number on search field` that means you want to search for that query, am i right? you want to place your own query in the box and virtually press submit?